# Customize login page of wso2is?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to customize the login page of wso2 identity server 5.1.0 and change it with the login page of wso2 identity server 5.0.0.
how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can update the login jsp at `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint/login.jsp` with the one you require. Additionally you can follow
[this page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Customizing+Login+Pages+for+Service+Providers) which contains instructions on how to customize the login pages.